# AsyncTask and Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have application that sends (multiple text files) to server and progress bar is updated on each file send & get response. It is dismissed once all files has been sent.

I have successfully implement this by calling send function inside a loop and progress bar gets updated.   Now I want to AsyncTask to execute the http request for each file and meanwhile progress bar gets updated as well.

How do I define AsyncTask to send specific file and get the response. On every file it sends, progress bar is also gets updated?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

-Sam

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? How to pass a parameter to an AsyncTask? Or how to update the ProgressBar from the Asynctask?

Comment: I am calling `new PostDataAsyncTask().execute(currentFile)` inside loop of progressbar it throws exception i.e. AsyncTask can't be called in Non UI thread. How do I then updated ProgressBar and where do I create AsyncTask instance?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your `ProgressBar` while still executing in your `AsyncTask`, you should...

- Implement the `onProgressUpdate(...)` method in your `AsyncTask`.
- Call `publishProgress(...)` when you want to update your progress bar during `doInBackground(...)`

There is an example of this in the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered in numerous places. The key is using `doInBackground()` method to perform the network activity and then you can call `publishProgress()` from there as you need in order to update the dialog. You will also need to override `onProgressUpdate()` since this is the method called by `publishProgress()` and will be where you put the code for your dialog.

- [Android documentation for `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [android how to work with asynctasks progressdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450275/android-how-to-work-with-asynctasks-progressdialog)
- [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)
- [How to use Asynctask effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461477/how-to-use-asynctask-effectively)
- [How to use AsyncTask correctly in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)
- more...

Comment: My progress bar spawns in a new thread on button click in main UI thread. Where do I then instantiate AsyncTask? and in this case how do I start progressBar?

Comment: The idea is, you initiate the AsyncTask in order to do the network I/O for sending your files, and once a file completes, you can call `publishProgress()`, optionally with some parameter. Once you do that, it triggers `onProgressUpdate()` and that is where you should update your ProgressBar. Not the way you are describing it by "spawning a new thread when the button is clicked". Please read the documentation and links.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the AsyncTask from the main/UI thread. You can't start an AsyncTask from a background thread. 
Try calling `new PostDataAsyncTask().execute(currentFile)` from onCreate(). 
As Yjay mentioned, you can use `onProgressUpdate()` and `publishProgress()`  for updating the ProgressBar's value.